# Css positioning - align two elements

Tags: html, css

I have two elements called #news and aside. They are both within the main element.

```
main {
    margin: 1.25em auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 96%;
    max-width:1200px;
}

#news{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
    width: 65.3%;
}

aside { 
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 3%;
    padding: 0em;
    width: 30.6%;
}
```

The #news element and aside element are both horizontal aligned (which is what I want). Within the aside element there is a section, the problem is they are not aligned with the #news element. there is some space between the top border of the aside element and the section element. I just don't know why there is this space...

EDIT: Here is the Html code:

```
<main>

        <section id="news">
            <h1>Just a title</h1>
            <p>Jsdf oisdfsd oisdjf oisjdf oisdfj oisdfj oisdjfisdfj oisjdfisd  tadatatatasdifjasodfijasdfj iosjdfiosa iojsdiofjsd ijsdifjsdifjdsi ijsidfjij isjdfisjd pasok poasdko iasfsid oiasjf iosjd i isdf isfdifj</p>
        </section>

        <aside>
            <section id="aside_social">
                <ul>
                    <li>Twitter</li>
                    <li>Facebook</li>
                    <li>Youtube</li>
                </ul>
            </section>

            <section id="aside_newsletter">

            </section>
        </aside>

    </main>
```

Comment: where is the markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```
 aside ul{margin-top:0;}
```

Here is the demo

```css
main {
    margin: 1.25em auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 96%;
    max-width:1200px;
}

#news{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
    width: 65.3%;
}

aside { 
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 3%;
    padding: 0em;
    width: 30.6%;
}

aside ul{margin-top:0;}
```

```html
<main>

        <section id="news">
            <h1>Just a title</h1>
            <p>Jsdf oisdfsd oisdjf oisjdf oisdfj oisdfj oisdjfisdfj oisjdfisd  tadatatatasdifjasodfijasdfj iosjdfiosa iojsdiofjsd ijsdifjsdifjdsi ijsidfjij isjdfisjd pasok poasdko iasfsid oiasjf iosjd i isdf isfdifj</p>
        </section>

        <aside>
            <section id="aside_social">
                <ul>
                    <li>Twitter</li>
                    <li>Facebook</li>
                    <li>Youtube</li>
                </ul>
            </section>

            <section id="aside_newsletter">

            </section>
        </aside>

    </main>
```

Answer (score 0):

*All* block elements (like `<h1>` `<h4>` `<div>` `<p>` `<ul>` `<section>`etc.) have their *own* default margin and padding settings, or rather each browser (and each framework or CMS like Bootstrap etc.) has its default settings for them. So if in two aligned blocks the contents of the left one start with an `<h3>`tag, and in the other one with a `<p>`tag, those two will most likely have different `margin-top and/or`padding-top`settings.
To align them anyways, you can use CSS classes or style attributes on them that give them identical settings for these parameters.

Comment: **Or** you can use a CSS reset stylesheet to get rid of the default browser styles : http://cssreset.com/

Comment: yes, but this will also change a lot of other things which might not be desired in an otherwise already set up page.